# Gradle war ignores transitive dependencies when using 'configurations.runtime.asPath' in custom task

Tags: gradle

I'm facing behavior that I can't explain, using gradle 1.10 I have:

**settings.gradle:**

```
include('lib1', 'lib2', 'web')
```

**build.gradle:**

```
subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
}

project(':web') {
  apply plugin: 'war'
  dependencies {
    compile project(':lib1')
  }

  task myTask(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: 'compileJava') {
        main = "some.thirdparty.Class"
        args "--searchPath", configurations.runtime.asPath
  }

}

project(':lib1') {
  dependencies {
    compile project(':lib2')
  }
}

project(':lib2') {
}
```

When I run `gradle clean war` I only have `lib1.jar` in `war/build/libs/web.war/WEB-INF/lib`.

To make `WEB-INF/lib` contain both `lib1.jar` and `lib2.jar` I have to:

- move `project('web')` block to the end of the file
- update `configurations.runtime.asPath` to `configurations.runtime` (but I need to provide class path as a path, so it is not a solution)

I read the [build lifecycle](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) description, tried to compare --debug outputs but that didn't help.

Why is this happening? And what would be a good solution to provide the module runtime class path as a path in JavaExec task please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asPath` resolves the configuration, but resolution will only work correctly if it happens at execution time rather than configuration time (in particular in the presence of project dependencies). Try to wrap the `args` line with `doFirst { ... }`.